# How to fix this error appearing when I programatically set tab bg color?

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

I use this code to set custom background color to my tabs

```
//setting up the tabs
res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, First.class);

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("One")
        .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Second.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("Two")
        .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.color.light);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.color.light);
tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.color.light);

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

When the page loads, all is fine and Tab 0 appears. But when I click on the second tab, the app crashes and I get an error

```
10-06 10:54:39.516: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.TabWidget.focusCurrentTab(TabWidget.java:370)
        at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
        at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:132)
        at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

PS. If I comment the 3 lines that set bg colors, the tab widget works without errors.

Comment: add this line TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); instead of TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem and the fix was nice and simple:

You need to set the divider drawable BEFORE you add tabs to the TabHost.

So the following line:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.color.light);
```

should be moved up. You can call if directly after:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```

For me, this solved the problem. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Do null check for child before setting the color ..

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
 //setting up the tabs
res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, First.class);

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("One")
        .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Second.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("Two")
        .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);    

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setTabColor(tabHost);
        }
});

setTabColor(tabHost);
```

here is the setTabColor() method:

```
//Change The Backgournd Color of Tabs
public void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {

    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(COLOR_DARK); //unselected

        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(COLOR_LIGHT); // selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please! remove below line from your code:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.color.light);
```